# How to convert a factor type into a numeric type in R after reading a csv file?

Tags: r

After reading a csv file

```
data<-read.table(paste0('C:/Users/data/','30092017ARB.csv'),header=TRUE, sep=";")
```

I get for rather all numeric variable `factor` as the type, specially for the last column. 
[image]

I tried all suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information) However, I get a warning for all suggestions

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Some one mentioned even in this post:

"Every answer in this post failed to generate results for me , NAs were getting generated."

any idea how can I solve this problem?

**Addendum**: in the following pic you can see one possible approach suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)

[image]

However, I get always the same `NA` .

Comment: can out look at which are na? It is possible that you missing that data...

Comment: 1) The percent sign is clearly the problem. Do `data[[3]] <- sub("%", "", data[[3]])` then convert to numeric. 2) When reading, in order to avoid problems with factors use argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Comment: 3) Are your data coming from countries where the decimal point is a comma? If so, consider `read.csv2`. See `help("read.table")`. for details. (`read.csv` and `read.csv2` are just `read.table` with some defaults changed.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks a lot. You are principally right. The problem is just with "%" . Would you write your comment as an answer, then I can accept your answer.

Comment: @maniA Done, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percent sign is clearly the problem. Replace the `"%"` by the empty string, `""`, and then convert to numeric.

```
data[[3]] <- sub("%", "", data[[3]]) 
data[[3]] <- as.numeric(data[[3]])
```

You can do this in one line of code,

```
data[[3]] <- as.numeric(sub("%", "", data[[3]]))
```

Also, two notes on reading the data in.

First, some files use the semi-colon as a column separator. This is very used in countries where the decimal point is the comma. That is why R has *two* functions to read files in the CSV format.

These functions are both calls to `read.table` with some defaults changed.

- `read.csv` - Sets arguments `header = TRUE` and `sep = ","`.
- `read.csv2` - Sets arguments `header = TRUE`, `sep = ";"` and `dec = ","`.

For a full explanation see [read.table](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) or at an R prompt run `help("read.table")`.

Second, you can avoid `factor` problems if you use argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` from the start, when reading in the data.